# resizable jQuery UI doen't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I wonder why my resizable() jQuery UI function doesn't work on my img.
http://impress-builder.herokuapp.com/home

here is the code: https://github.com/lipenco/impress.js-app

```
function setResizable(){
    $( ".resizable" ).resizable();

   }

   $(document).on('click', 'img', function(event){ 
      $(this).addClass('resizable');
      $(this).css("position" ,"absolute")
      setResizable(); 
      return false;
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot be able to find error in it. but if you can provide me the exact reference as to where is the exact code written on to the page as I cannot be able to explore code on the webpage you referenced. Please elaborate more for help.

Example : `$(document).find('.resizable').resizable();`

Or directly on to the page through browser Console.

Here's a jsfiddle code with static element : http://jsfiddle.net/coolshivster/eUKhA/

**Try Resolving it** by placing your `jQuery-ui` file on to the head or before `img.js`

Comment: [here is the website from iframe](http://impress-builder.herokuapp.com/content?layout=vertical&num_slides=8&shape=rectangle&automated=false&theme=basic&substeps=false&progress_bar=no-pbar)  I am usung popline for editing the content and to put images from url

Comment: Try resolving it by placing your jQuery-ui on to the head or before your img.js

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you can resize an image directly ? I suggest wrapping it in a div.
http://jsfiddle.net/8VY52/

You can create a div on the fly. Ho, also, you must set the div `style="display:inline-block"`